# Issue mounting docker volume with docker-compose

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-machine

### My Scenario

I am trying to build docker swarm with `docker-compose.yml` file

```
version: '3'

services:
  myapp-nginx:
    image: nginx:1.10
    volumes:
     - ./nginx/certs:/etc/nginx/certs
    ports:
      - 80:80
      - 443:443
```

using build command as below

```
$ docker stack deploy --compose-file docker-compose.yml myapp

Creating network myapp_default
Creating service myapp_myapp-nginx
```

My system have `Docker Version 17.03.1-ce-mac5 (16048)`

### Problem

Volumes mounts are not working, If I comment out `volumes:  - ./nginx/certs:/etc/nginx/certs` then everything works fine.

Otherwise nginx doesn't work at all, I see

```
CAGTAM1059934:docker iskumar$ docker stack ps myapp
ID            NAME                  IMAGE       NODE      DESIRED STATE  CURRENT STATE            ERROR                             PORTS
efjia8b7y6jd  myapp_myapp-nginx.1      nginx:1.10  manager1  Ready          Rejected 5 seconds ago   "invalid mount config for type…"  
c9c6ogh11osi   \_ myapp_myapp-nginx.1  nginx:1.10  worker2   Shutdown       Rejected 10 seconds ago  "invalid mount config for type…"  
iveikxpnbq6x   \_ myapp_myapp-nginx.1  nginx:1.10  worker1   Shutdown       Rejected 15 seconds ago  "invalid mount config for type…"
```

Is there any special way to mount volumes in docker-compose v3?

Answer (score 0):

You must use absolute paths when mounting volumes, also with **docker run**.

```
$ docker run --rm -it -v ./eos:/eos:ro ubuntu 
docker: Error response from daemon: create ./eos: "./eos" includes invalid characters for a local volume name, only "[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9_.-]" are allowed. If you intented to pass a host directory, use absolute path.
See 'docker run --help'
```

Comment: Absolute path still doesn't work e.g.  `/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/myapp/docker/nginx/certs:/etc/nginx/certs:ro`

Comment: I get `invalid mount config for type` error, although same script works fine on macbook native docker installation using `docker-compose up -d`. But I get into problem after switching into docker cluster with command `eval $(docker-machine env manager1)` and deploying with `docker stack deploy`.

Comment: Is that the complete message error?  By digging in the Docker code, there are multiple posibilities.

Comment: I using `docker stack ps myapp` to view logs which results in `Error: "invalid mount config for type…"` is there any other command to view detailed logs?

Comment: I need the "..."

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/139512/discussion-between-ish-and-ricardo-branco).

Answer (score 0):

I was running `docker stack deploy` from my macbook instead on boot2docker VMs. Which is why system couldn't find those network mount source, even though I had manager1 activated using `eval $(docker-machine env manager1)`

First I used --no-trunc argument to view full error message.

```
$> docker node ps --no-trunc
---
Showed "invalid mount config for type "bind": bind source path does not exist"  
---
```

After that copies the files from host system (*My MacBook*) to VM and launching stack worked fine.

Credit to https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/31202#issuecomment-281312704