# How to map volume from Jenkins workspace to Docker container with docker-compose

Tags: postgresql, docker, jenkins, docker-compose

I have a `docker-compose.yaml` that spins up an express server and [postgres database](https://hub.docker.com/_/postgres) in separate containers. The postgres container maps a volume to a `db` folder, which contains database seeding scripts. Locally, docker-compose runs fine and I can execute integration tests against the networked containers. However, the same scripts fail when running on Jenkins, with the following error:

> ERROR: for db  Cannot start service db: error while creating mount
>   source path
>   '/var/jenkins_home/workspace/project_name/db':
>   mkdir /var/jenkins_home: read-only file system

**docker-compose.yaml**

```
...

db:
    image: postgres:10.5
    restart: always
    networks:
      - cloud
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: someuser
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: somepassword
      POSTGRES_DB: somedb
    ports:
      - 5432:5432
    volumes:
      - ./db:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD-SHELL", "pg_isready -U someuser -d somedb"]
      interval: 10s
      timeout: 5s
      retries: 5
```

I have read in [several](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43105101/issue-mounting-docker-volume-with-docker-compose) [places](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43230651/docker-compose-how-to-mapping-volume-from-host-into-container) that volumes require absolute paths (not relative), but I tried harcoding `/var/jenkins_home/workspace/project_name/db` to the left side of the volume config to no avail.

Comment: You must set the correct permissions in the host before you mount volumes try something like sudo chown 1000 volume_dir

Comment: Is Jenkins also running in Docker?  Bind-mount volume paths are always host paths and never paths in a container, so if `/var/jenkins_home` in a container isn't a bind-mount of `/var/jenkins_home` on the host, the path will be wrong and you'll get this error.

Comment: Yes, Jenkins is also running in Docker. I used these instructions: https://jenkins.io/doc/book/installing/ and therefore these two volume mappings: `-v jenkins-data:/var/jenkins_home -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock`

Comment: AFAIU @DavidMaze got the point